# VS2017 Xamarin android emulator started by can't connect

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation

I have created and started an android emulator from the Android Device Manager in VS2017. But I can't seem to find the device in the dropdown list, which only contains Live Players.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try [Android Emulator Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/) or [Android Emulator Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?tabs=vswin)